# How to add a NavigationPage inside a TabbedPage in MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have a structure like the below one.

```
TabbedPage
    TabbedPage
        ContentPage
        ContentPage
    NavigationPage
        ContentPage -> ContentPage
    ContentPage
    NavigationPage
        ContentPage -> ContentPage
```

I am able to recreate this structure with Prism, but I need it in MvvmCross.
The problem is when I add the NavigationPage to the tabbed page then it shows only the NavigationPage -> ContentPage and does not overlay the TabbedPage which is the parent.

I want the TabbedPage (Which is a custom TabbedPage) to be the RootLevel of the app and always visible.

Not sure how to do it with a ViewModel based Navigation approach.
There aren't too many samples which have complex navigation structure like this.
Can anyone suggest if this is possible?
Else what could be an alternative.

Comment: Did you try remove the navigation page wrap? Like this: `[MvxTabbedPagePresentation(WrapInNavigationPage = false, Title = "Tab1")]` ? by default WrapInNavigationPage is true

Comment: @FabriBertani : I've added     ?`[MvxTabbedPagePresentation(TabbedPosition.Tab, WrapInNavigationPage = false)]` I've changed WrapInNavigationPage to both false and true but the result doesn't change